# How to get page-aligned memory from operator new or malloc for mremap

Tags: c++, c, posix

Is there a way to allocate a block of memory so that its starting address is aligned with a given page size? Note that I do not want to calculate the aligned address after the block has been allocated. The reason is that at some point I will have to call mremap() on the block: mremap requires the old address argument to be page-aligned.

Comment: What's wrong with doing something like _mm_malloc(sizeof(Float)*n, 4096)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use system specific alloocation routines - which isn't a huge deal, since you are also using a system-dependent mremap function. However, you also need to be careful with what you place in the memory (e.g. using placement `new` will not work well) because mremap may change the address of the memory when you change it's size.

Since you are most likely using Linux for this, have you considered an anonymous `mmap` region? That would behave the same as malloc, except it's automatically page-aligned anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by "mmap region" exactly? Are you taliing about a shared memory segment? If yes, I am not sure there is a guarantee it's aligned (at least not in boost::interprocess)

Comment: The system call `mmap` gives you a page-aligned memory region.

Answer (score 2):

`mremap` may only safely be used on memory regions allocated by `mmap`, which are inherently page-aligned. Using it on anything else is dangerous (formally, undefined behavior) and may appear to work but will probably badly break things in ways that you won't see right away.

Answer (score 1):

Some malloc packages provide this feature but it is not standardized.

[posix version](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign)